# joomla component blank pages

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, components

How to debug blank pages in joomla 2.5 during development. I try to access my custom components on view and sub controller like

```
index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=item&id=2571

index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=item.display&id=2571
```

but I'm getting blank pages. Where to escape this error?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In global configuration set your error reporting to development. Then you will see the error messages. Also you might want to turn on debug in global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it wouldn't help.

Try to add strings in the file com_yourcomponent/yourcomponent.php (just after '< ?php'):

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```